# FadeIn not working after appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, fade

I have done a table structure appending this way:

```
var table = $('<table></table>');

table.append($('<tr>').append($('<td>')
                         .addClass('col2 linhaSub')
                         .append($('<span>')
                           .toggleClass('alterado', modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].Efeito)//returns true or false
                           .text(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].ID))
            ))
```

After the table creation, I'm trying to make all the "alterado" status have a fade effect with this method:

```
$( "span" ).each(function( i ) {

if ( this.className === "alterado" ) {
 $(this).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
}
});

$("body").html(table);
```

The after entering the IF, the fade effect isnt being applied and if I add `.fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300)` when I append the `span`, it works like a charm. I can't do that because its conditional and its for many spans.

What I'm doing wrong to make this fadeIn works properly the way I'm trying?

The IF is returning true, since I debugged it and checked.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use $('.alterado').fadeIn....

Comment: @xd6_ already tried that, no success.. No fades..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the issues pointed out by **@Bellash** were typos while writing the question, your code works fine: [**see this working fiddle with proper syntax and indentation**](http://jsfiddle.net/wELGM/).

As you have pointed out, the `modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].Efeito` is returning `true`: it means that it should work and pass through the if statement.

---

What can be an issue is **what** you are doing with the **`table`** variable, and **when**. Make sure that you are appending the created table after asking its spans to fade. Look how I have accomplished that in the aforementioned fiddle:

```
var table = $('<table></table>');

table.append(
    $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').addClass('col2 linhaSub').append(
            $('<span>').toggleClass('alterado', true).text("test")
        )
    )
);

$("body").append(table);

$("span").each(function(i) {
    if (this.className === "alterado") {
       $(this).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Its a typo..I will correct it. Anyway, I debugged in firefox and is returning true, passing through it and doing nothing

Comment: Found my mistake. Im doing `$("body").html(table)' AFTER the fade. If I put it before works great.. I will update my question so then you can updte ur answer to keep the good info avaliable

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. Please, verify whether it addresses your issue properly, or needs further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing a closing `)` at the end. in addition, `var` not `Var`

```
   var table = $('<table></table>');

 table.append($('<tr>').append($('<td>')
                     .addClass('col2 linhaSub')
                     .append($('<span>')
         .toggleClass('alterado', modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].Efeito)
                       .text(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].ID))
        ))
```